# Virt-manager: unable to open a connection to the libvirt management daemon

Tags: virtualization, fedora, libvirt, virt-manager

I'm having a bit of trouble connecting to my virtual machine host, which is an Ubuntu server running KVM/Libvirt. I can connect to the server using an Ubuntu client and I can connect via virsh on a Fedora 16 client. Unfortunately, connecting via virt-manager fails with the error: "unable to open a connection to the libvirt management daemon".

Comment: Is *libvirtd* running on the system?

Comment: Yes: bshacklett@edo:~$ ps aux | grep libvirtd
1000      2347  0.0  0.0   7620   920 pts/0    S+   16:54   0:00 grep libvirtd
root     26368  0.0  0.0 216880  5252 ?        Sl   Sep26   0:02 /usr/sbin/libvirtd -d

Comment: I attempted to connect with virt-manager on an OpenSuse box last night and experienced the same issue. It seems to me that this is more of a server-side issue than client-side. Is there a chance that Ubuntu (or Debian) doing something strange with the Libvirt packages? I plan to take a network trace with Wireshark tonight if I don't get wrapped up in other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to install the openssh-askpass package.